# Uses of TensorBoard Projector besides word embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, tensorflow

I was wondering, are any examples of using the projector in TensorBoard for anything other than visualizing word embedding in natural language processing? It seems like a pretty general tool for dimension reduction and visualization, but the only examples I have encountered in my limited experience are restricted to NLP and embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web API for [the TensorBoard Projector](https://projector.tensorflow.org/) is just a cute GUI for $t$-SNE and PCA. Anything that be productively visualized using $t$-SNE or PCA is a great candidate to be used with the TensorBoard Projector.